# OkHttp interceptor keep returning null and crashing the app

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I have an OkHttp client which uses my custom network interceptor in order to insert token into requests header.

I keep on getting the exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher 
   Process: com.edstart.tazuzu, PID: 32093
   java.lang.NullPointerException: interceptor com.edstart.tazuzu.RestAPI.RequestsErrorInterceptor@2bde70f returned null
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:157)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at com.edstart.tazuzu.RestAPI.TazuzuRequestsInterceptor.intercept(TazuzuRequestsInterceptor.kt:30)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I have tried surrounding the interceptor with try/catch. and also throwing error in order to avoid app crash but with no good results.

The interceptor code:

```
package com.edstart.tazuzu.RestAPI

import android.util.Log
import com.edstart.tazuzu.Managers.ServerManager
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response
import java.net.InetAddress
import kotlin.Exception

/**
 * interceptor for the tazuzu api requests to insert the token before the request
 * send to the server (for authentication)
 */
class TazuzuRequestsInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response? {
        try {

            if (!isInternetAvailable()) {
                throw Exception()
            } else {
                var request = chain?.request()

                if (request != null) {
                    val builder = request.newBuilder()
                    if (builder != null) {
                        builder.addHeader("x-access-token", ServerManager.token)

                        request = builder.build()
                        if (request != null && chain != null) {
                            return chain.proceed(request)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Log.e("###", e.toString())
            throw e
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
        return try {
            val ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com")
            //You can replace it with your name
            !ipAddr.equals("")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }

    }
```

Please help, looking for ways controlling exceptions in a way it won't make the app crash.

Comment: The stacktrace says it's `RequestsErrorInterceptor` and not `TazuzuRequestsInterceptor` you posted.

Comment: when you take all your code in try/catch, why take a lot of if/else? :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Few notes**

You shouldn't pass `null` in the interceptor

**What went wrong**

Null is passed to the downstream chain

**What you can do**

```
class ErrorHandlingInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)

        if (!isInternetAvailable()) {
            // Do your thing
            // 1. Either throw a generic exception
            // 2. Throw an exception with your own custom status code that can be checked on the callbacks
            // 3. Create an interface callback

            // example throw invocation
            throw Exception()
        } else {
            val builder = request.newBuilder()
            builder?.let { builder ->
                builder.addHeader("x-access-token", ServerManager.token)
            }
            request = builder.build()

            // No need for this additional checks
            // if (request != null && chain != null) { ... }

            return chain.proceed(request)
        }
    }
}


private fun isInternetAvailable(): Boolean {
    return try {
        val ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com")
        //You can replace it with your name
        !ipAddr.equals("")

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        false
    }

}
```

If for example, you have chosen to throw an exception when there's no internet connection, you could just handle everything in `onFailure()`callback of the `retrofit` call.

Or if you are using `rxjava`, you can just subscribe for the error on the error callback handler.

**Read more on**

- https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-catch-server-errors-globally-with-response-interceptor
- https://medium.com/@tsaha.cse/advanced-retrofit2-part-1-network-error-handling-response-caching-77483cf68620

Comment: Thank you. that helped me a lot to understand how things should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. it did. also voted up your answer, but my votes are not counted yet :)

Comment: No worries, happy to help. :)

Comment: It's great that this solves my problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when tried to launch request in Main Thread. Try to use coroutines, just wrap your Retrofit-request call with CoroutineScope:

```
val apiService = RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService()

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

        val response = apiService.myPostRequest()

        // process response...

    }
```